# Properly insert text into Android Application

Tags: java, android, string.xml

I recently started an Android project as some sort of tutorial, but rather than the same boring List/Web View most android offline tutorial app make use of, I decided to make a it a bit better using Recycler View and card View.

The main problem so far(even it may not be to the end user as long as the app works anyway) is putting the **text** in cardview(had no problem with images and other res) as my strings.xml is filled up and everything looks rough.

```
<resources>
        <string name="lesson_galaxy_one_intro"> <h1><span style="color:red">Welcome to My ..... Course</span></h1>]]>   </string>
    <string name="lesson_galaxy_two_intro"> <![CDATA[   
        <h1><span style="color:red">Getting to know .....</span></h1>   ]]>     </string>
        
<string name="galaxy_one_main_neration">    <![CDATA[<h1> <span style="color:red">  ]]> </string>
        <string name="galaxy_one_main_Overview">    </string>
        <string name="b">   <![CDATA[   ]]></string>
    <string name="c">   <![CDATA[   ]]></string></resources>
```

This is more of my first real project, I just want to ask how do developers package their Text. Is  strings.xml the right option for apps that require many texts? Please any tip could be helpful.